# Java Stream digits to number

Tags: java, java-stream, biginteger

I am struggling to get a functioning code for this.
I have a stream of digits between 0 and 9. I want to get a `BigInteger` out of those digits.
Example:

```
IntStream digits = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3) // should get me a Biginteger 123.
IntStream digits = IntStream.of(9, 5, 3) // should get me a Biginteger 953.
```

Is there a way to concatenate all elements out of the stream?
Here is my basic idea:

```
digits.forEach(element -> result=result.concat(result, element.toString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could map each digit to a string, join them all together and then create a `BigInteger` from it:

```
BigInteger result =
    IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)
             .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
             .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.joining(), 
                                                    BigInteger::new));
```

Comment: Looks good and makes sense, but I'm getting "The constructor BigInteger(Object) is undefined". Also, I need to add an Assertion if the stream has numbers above 9. But if I check the stream before then it's getting closed and I can't use it anymore. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce as follows:

```
BigInteger big1 = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
    .sequential() // if parallel, reduce would return sweet potatoes
    .reduce((a, b) -> a.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(b))
    .orElse(BigInteger.ZERO);

System.out.println(big1); // 123456789
```

Though I think it would be better to create a `String` and use it as the argument of `BigInteger`'s constructor, as in @Mureinik's answer. Here I'm using a variant that doesn't create a `String` object per digit:

```
String digits = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString();
BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger(digits);

System.out.println(big2); // 123456789
```

Answer (score 2):

You were not doing that too bad, minor changes that I would suggest is using `forEachOrdered`, because `forEach` does not guarantee order for parallel streams and collection that to a `StringBuilder`. Something like:

```
IntStream digits = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
digits.forEachOrdered(sb::append);
System.out.println(new BigInteger(sb.toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
BigInteger res = new BigInteger(IntStreamEx.of(1, 2, 3).joining(""));
```

Or maybe we should remove the prefix '0' if that could happen

```
BigInteger res = new BigInteger(IntStreamEx.of(0, 1, 2).dropWhile(i -> i == 0).joining(""));
```

And maybe we should add the check for empty stream:

```
String str = IntStreamEx.of(0, 1, 2).dropWhile(i -> i == 0).joining("")
BigInteger res = str.length() == 0 ? BigInteger.ZERO : new BigInteger(str);
```